# How to do lazy and strict positioning of circles/diamonds/arrows in Tikz Mindmap?

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps, debian

I am trying to do functional behaviour analysis with Tikz Mindmap where I need the following units and connections.

1. diamond symbol - strictly on the left-most
2. circle symbol - lazy positioning
3. connections - single arrows and double arrows between a diamond and circles
4. connections positioning is strict between circles and diamonds

Terms

- `lazy` - position any anywhere on the result
- `greedy` - position at specific location, here at the most left-hand-side (= *left-most*)
- `left-most` - at the most left-hand-side

You can be lazy in putting the positions of circles but the diamonds should be greedy at the left-most. 
I think the approach is too greedy on the thread [Positioning Nodes In Tikz Below Left](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/197903/13173) with explicit positioning of all things.

The 12-node code example of the thread [Tikz Mindmap - how to get more nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7520/13173) where only circles, is a good starting point for putting cirles lazily.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   %% TODO
   % 1. Put a diamond at left most

   % 2. Make 12 circles lazily
   %https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7520/13173
  \path[mindmap,concept color=blue,text=white,
    level 1 concept/.append style=
      {every child/.style={concept color=blue!70},sibling angle=-30}]
      node[concept] {\Huge\bfseries TikZ}[clockwise from=0]
        child foreach \i in {1,...,12} {node[concept]{\LARGE\bfseries\i}};

   % 3. Create connections between diamond and circles

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

OS: Debian 8.7

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you are trying to do. What do you mean by `lazy`, `greedy` and `left most`? Why are you trying to use `mindmap` if you need diamonds? What have you tried exactly? See `shapes.geometric` for diamonds. Use `name` to name nodes. See `arrows.meta` for arrows.

Comment: @cfr I think you understand very well me when I look at your answer. I added explicit definitions of those terms - I borrowed some of the therminology in data structures and algorithms.

Comment: Why don't you just say 'I don't care where the circles go, but the diamond needs to be furthest left'? Introducing discipline-specific terms just makes your question harder to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what is meant by `lazy` or `greedy` here.

The easiest way to place the diamond is to draw it after the mind map.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shapes.geometric,arrows.meta,positioning}
\begin{document}
% cwestiwn éo Léopold Hertz 준영: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364288/how-to-do-lazy-and-strict-positioning-of-circles-diamonds-arrows-in-tikz-mindmap
\begin{tikzpicture}
   %http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7520/13173
   \path
   [mindmap,
   concept color=blue,
   text=white,
   level 1 concept/.append style={every child/.style={concept color=blue!70}, sibling angle=-30}
   ]
   node [concept, font=\Huge\bfseries] {Ti\emph{k}Z}
   [clockwise from=0]
   child foreach \i in {1,...,12} {node (c\i) [concept, font=\LARGE\bfseries]{\i}};
   \node (d) [left=of c7, text width=50mm, fill, diamond, draw, magenta] {};
   \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using {\i>6 ? -45-(12-\i)*15 : 55+\i*15}, evaluate=\i as \k using { \i>6 ? -90+(12-\i)*5 : 90-((\i-1)*5)} ] in {1,...,12} \draw [gray, ultra thick, -Latex] (d) [out=\k, in=\j] to (c\i);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: diamond and arrows]

Comment: I bet that OP wants the thick, gradient color connection between diamond and circles

Comment: @Symbol1 I wondered about that, but how would it work with arrows?

Comment: @Symbol1 Can you give an example what you mean as your own answer?

Comment: What is this inner structure surrounded by 12 circles called? Can it be just a circle? Can arrows point from the inner TikZ structure point to smaller circles?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 That structure is called mindmap.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 I don't know what you mean. You were the one who started with that structure rather than something else. That's just how `mindmap` mind maps look. If you want something else, obviously don't use a `mindmap`.